# Modify script for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, zipcode

The script below does exactly what I need, when I enter a zip code it automatically brings up the city and state.

However, because I'm not really familiar with the code, I have a problem with modifying it.

As of now, it places the City in the targeted cell and creates a new cell/row underneath for state and zip code

What I want it to do is place the city in the desired cell, place the state in the next cell/column to the right and not place the zip code at all since I have it already...

Also, as of now if there's no zip code entered #ERROR appears I would like for it to be blank...

this is the code:

```
function lat(pointa) {
 var response = Maps.newGeocoder()
     .geocode(pointa);
  return response.results[0].geometry.location.lat
}
function long(pointa) {
  var response = Maps.newGeocoder()
     .geocode(pointa);
  return response.results[0].geometry.location.lng
}
function zip2city(zip) {
  var response=Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(lat(zip), long(zip));
  return response.results[0].formatted_address.split(',').slice(1,3);
}
```

Paste this (these) into your Script editor. Then in a cell put in =zip2city(A1), or whatever cell the zip code is in.

Thanks In advance.....

Comment: It seems like there is something missing, how are you getting the zip?

Comment: I don't know. I found this code on line and it works.